# The double cover of $[W(E_7),W(E_7)] \cong Sp_6(\mathbb F_2)$ as a Galois group over $\mathbb Q$

Tags: finite-groups, weyl-group, exceptional-groups, galois-groups, classical-groups

I came across the following problem when I was trying to construct a certain type of homomorphisms from $\Gamma_{\mathbb Q}$ to $E^{sc}_7(\mathbb F_p)$ for any prime $p$:

**Is the *double cover* of $Sp_6(\mathbb F_2)(=PSp_6(\mathbb F_2))$ known as a Galois group over $\mathbb Q$?**

A little background about $Sp_6(\mathbb F_2)$: It is a finite simple group of order $2^9\cdot 3^4 \cdot 5 \cdot 7$ with Schur multiplier 2 (sometimes denoted by $C_3(2)$). So it possesses a unique non-trivial two-fold central extension which I shall denote by $\widetilde{Sp_6}(\mathbb F_2)$. It is a quasisimple group. On the other hand, $Sp_6(\mathbb F_2)$ is isomorphic to the derived subgroup of the Weyl group of type $E_7$ (denoted by $W=W(E_7)$), which is isomorphic to $Sp_6(\mathbb F_2)\times \{\pm 1\}$. The group $\widetilde{Sp_6}(\mathbb F_2)$ can be realized as the pullback of $Sp_6(\mathbb F_2) \cong [W,W] \to SO(7)$ along the projection $Spin(7) \to SO(7)$. Let $G=E_7^{sc}$ be the simply-connected Chevalley group of type $E_7$. Let $T$ be a maximal split torus of 
$G$. Consider the following exact sequence:
$$1\to T \to N_G(T) \to N_G(T)/T\cong W \to 1$$
By a result of J. Adams and X. He, https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.00510, the sequence does not split.

It is known that the Weyl group of a reductive group $G$ can be realized as a Galois group of a finite extension of $\mathbb Q$: the idea is that the Galois group of
the characteristic polynomial of $Ad(g)|_{\mathfrak g}$ for "generic" $g\in G(\mathbb Q)$ is isomorphic to the Weyl group of $G$, provided that $G/\mathbb Q$ is split. This dates back to E. Cartan's famous thesis 120 years ago! See Jouve, Kowalski and Zywina's paper https://people.math.ethz.ch/~kowalski/weyl-group-e8.pdf for a good account of this. 
In particular, the finite simple group $Sp_6(\mathbb F_2)$ can be realized as a Galois group over $\mathbb Q$ (being a direct summand of $W(E_7)$). To settle $\widetilde{Sp_6}(\mathbb F_2)$, it is natural to consider the embedding problem given by the non-split exact sequence:
$$1 \to \{\pm 1\} \to \widetilde{Sp_6}(\mathbb F_2) \to Sp_6(\mathbb F_2) \to 1$$ I don't know how to solve this problem. Any suggestions would be appreciated. On the other hand, since this group is a concrete group with generators and relations, I wonder if one can find a polynomial over $\mathbb Q$ that realizes it using computer algorithms.

Comment: A (probably useless) remark: F. Calagari mentioned a related question to me (that of realizing Tits groups as Galois groups). Perhaps you can look at recent papers of his students. (If I recall correctly one of his students was working on this problem, and it turned out to be tricky. I can't recall if they got anywhere.)

Comment: The obstruction to finding that lifting is a class in $H^2(\mathbb Q, \mathbb Z/2)$. Presumably there is a class in $H^2$ of the function field of $G(\mathbb Q)$ that pulls back to this obstruction. So the question is whether there is $g$ where the pullback of the Galois group is full and the pullback of this obstruction is trivial.

Comment: Re:Geordie. Thanks, that's good to know!

Comment: Re:Will. Can you please be a little more precise?

Answer (score 1):

More details on my comment:

I mean that there is an induced map $H^2( E_7^o , \mathbb Z/2)  \mathbb Z/2 =  H^2( W(E_7), \mathbb Z/2) \to H^2( \pi_1(E_7^o , \mathbb Z/2)) \to H^2( E_7^o , \mathbb Z/2)$ where $E_7^o$ is the open subset of regular semisimple elements and the map $\pi_1 ( E_7^o) \to W(E_7)$ is from the cover whose fiber over an element $g$ is the set of Borels containing $g$, which is a $W(E_7)$-torsor as $g$ is regular semisimple.

A $\mathbb Q$-point of $E_7^0$ such that the pullback of this cohomology class to $H^2(\mathbb Q, \mathbb Z/2)$ is trivial and such that the pullback of this $W(E_7)$-torsor to $\mathbb Q$ is irreducible gives a $W(E_7)$-extension of $\mathbb Q$ whose obstruction to lifting to the double cover vanishes.

I don't know whether it's possible to find $\mathbb Q$-points where this cohomology class vanishes (it's infinitely many local conditions) or whether it is possible to verify the Hilbert irreducibility theorem for this family.